# Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an issue with audio mixing in a flutter, I am getting return code 0 means success, but when I check the output audio file it's not playing properly.

This issue happens with some audio files

Expected behavior: every audio file can mix in another audio file

Current behavior: I am getting return code 0 means success, but when I have checked the output audio file it's not mix

Command.:String fileMixCommand = "-i "+ filepath1 +" -i "+filepath2+" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0 "+outputpath;

The output error from FFMpeg is as follows:

[mp3 @ 0xc7dcbc00] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it. I/flutter (12942): Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here and what I can do to fix this?

Comment: At least one of your audio files has cover art which is treated as a video stream. And ffmpeg is trying to convert it using its timebase. Long story short: add `-c:v copy`

Comment: @Gyan Where this -c:v copy add in my command?

Comment: Before output path.

Comment: String fileMixCommand= "-i "+filepath1+" -stream_loop -1 -i "+filepath2+" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0 -c:v copy "+output;

Comment: @Gyan Not working command.Please give me another solution

Comment: Show the complete log from the command.